# Strange empty lists produced by Itertools in Python

Tags: python, anaconda, python-itertools

I have list of dicts and i want to use itertools.groupby to rearrange it, the code is simple:

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted_animals = sorted(questions, key=itemgetter('intent'))
for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted_animals, key=lambda x:x['intent']):
    print(key),
    print(list(group))
    questions_grouped.append({key: list(group)})
print("questions_grouped:", questions_grouped)
pprint(questions_grouped)
```

This code works, i have got an expected result, new dict grouped by key, it is printed the following way:

```
greet
[{'intent': 'greet', 'text': 'Hi. Hi.'}, {'intent': 'greet', 'text': 'Hello'}]
```

**But, i really frustrated that if i look at list, created with these items i got all list empty!:**
That is super strange, assuming simple print is working and all lists must have content.
I use Python 3.6.5, Anaconda

```
questions_grouped:
[{'greet': []},
 {'ask_family1': []},
 {'ask_family10': []},
 {'ask_family11': []},
 {'ask_family12': []},
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(list(group))` for debug consumes `group` which is an iterable. Just remove it since it has a side effect.

```
print(list(group))  # prints and empties group. Remove that line
questions_grouped.append({key: list(group)})  # now list(group) is []
```

If you need debugging & printing, store the result in a variable first.

```
group = list(group)
print(group)
questions_grouped.append({key: group})
```